# Fire macro on cell color change

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have a sheet with some conditioned formatting.
In particular it changes from blank to red the background color a the cell when a particular condition occures.
Now I need a vba code to fire a macro when the colour changes in red.
I only know "if not intersect ... is nothing..." but it seems to not work if the background color is the only to change.
I really need to solve it!
I very appreciate any help.
Regards.
V78

Comment: There is no event that fires on background color change. Even the change of a formula value does not trigger any events. Only constant value changes trigger the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: There is one and I found it, but it works only with manual color change and nothing happens if it's conditional formatting to change it.

Comment: Which event does trigger a background color change? See link above your question. Make sure you use formatting as a result of information and not as information in itself. Make sure you trigger on values only not on formattings.